# Derby "&" is not working

Tags: derby

```
Select distinct APP.bca_cart.InventoryCode,APP.bca_cart.InventoryID,APP.bca_cart.CartID,APP.bca_cart.InvoiceID,APP.bca_cart.UnitPrice,APP.bca_cart.DateAdded,APP.bca_cart.CustomSku,APP.bca_cart.InventoryCode  & '-'  &  APP.bca_cart.CustomSku AS fullsku,APP.bca_cart.Qty AS O_QTY,APP.storage_clientvendor.FirstName,APP.storage_clientvendor.LastName,APP.storage_clientvendor.Name   FROM ((APP.bca_iteminventory INNER JOIN (APP.bca_cart INNER JOIN APP.bca_invoice   ON APP.bca_cart.InvoiceID = APP.bca_invoice.InvoiceID) ON APP.bca_iteminventory.InventoryID = APP.bca_cart.InventoryID)INNER JOIN APP.storage_clientvendor  ON APP.bca_invoice.ClientVendorID =APP.storage_clientvendor.ClientVendorID) Where APP.bca_iteminventory.StoreTypeID <= 0  AND APP.bca_iteminventory.ItemTypeID NOT IN (5,4,6) AND APP.bca_iteminventory.companyId =18 ORDER BY APP. storage_clientvendor.LastName ASC
```

I am getting following Stacktrace. please help me to solve this error.

```
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "&" at line 1, column 145.
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at com.bzcomposer.global.tables.tblItemLoader.getBackOrderItemListByCustomer(tblItemLoader.java:8488)
at com.bzcomposer.items.ItemListPanel$BackOrderItemModel.setTableData(ItemListPanel.java:4424)
at com.bzcomposer.items.ItemListPanel$BackOrderItemModel.<init>(ItemListPanel.java:4407)
at com.bzcomposer.items.ItemListPanel.<init>(ItemListPanel.java:140)
at com.bzcomposer.modules.internalPanel.SalesPanels.<init>(SalesPanels.java:90)
at com.bzcomposer.modules.internalPanel.InternalPanelsControl.init_internalPanel1(InternalPanelsControl.java:162)
at com.bzcomposer.modules.MainFrame2.init_internalframe1(MainFrame2.java:1104)
at com.bzcomposer.modules.MainFrame2.invokeInit(MainFrame2.java:816)
at com.bzcomposer.modules.MainPanel$1.run(MainPanel.java:393)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Syntax error: Encountered "&" at line 1, column 145.
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
... 17 more
Caused by: ERROR 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "&" at line 1, column 145.
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ParserImpl.parseStatement(Unknown Source)
```

i search a lot on internet but still i am not getting solution of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you would like to concatinate the strings by using `&`.

For concatination you have to use `||`

```
APP.bca_cart.InventoryCode  || '-'  ||  APP.bca_cart.CustomSku
```

Comment: After Done with above change i am getting new error in same query.

Comment: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Column 'APP.BCA_CUSTOMSELECT.QTY' is either not in any table in the FROM list or appears within a join specification and is outside the scope of the join specification or appears in a HAVING clause and is not in the GROUP BY list. If this is a CREATE or ALTER TABLE  statement then 'APP.BCA_CUSTOMSELECT.QTY' is not a column in the target table.
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)

Comment: What is `APP` in your query? The database Schema or what?